# Setting Different Color For Text Inside A TextView Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I have put in my app one textview inside a fragment. Each page has a different text. I want every time you find for example the word "tree", this word is painted color red and the rest words white. How could I do it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("tree");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourTextViewText);

final SpannableStringBuilder spannableBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(yourTextViewText);
final ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
while (matcher.find()) {
    spannableBuilder.setSpan(
        span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
yourTextView.setText(spannableBuilder);
```

This will replace all the word "tree" with RED Color.

[See More About Pattern Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the text, use:

textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);